# File explorer content won't open

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I had upgraded my windows 7 to windows 10, but I have this problem of opening the content of the file explorer. Even my drives and USB plug in, and it displays " working on it" when I press it, then it will close down the explorer.

How do I resolve this?